# Best practice for executing commands from K8s .yaml files

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, command

My .yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: foo
  namespace: bar
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: $DOCKERHUB_REGISTRY_SECRET
      containers:
        - name: django
          image: $DOCKERHUB_USER/$DOCKERHUB_IMAGENAME:$VERSION
          command: [ 'python manage.py makemigrations' ]
          :
```

However I see a lot of alternatives for `command`:

```
          command: [ 'python', 'manage.py', 'makemigrations' ]
```

```
          command: [ '/bin/sh -c', 'python', 'manage.py', 'makemigrations' ]
```

```
          command: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
          args: [ 'python', 'manage.py', 'makemigrations' ]
```

```
          command: [ 'python' ]
          args: [ 'manage.py', 'makemigrations' ]
```

etc.

Aesthetically I prefer the last approach, as it clearly separates the command from the arguments.

But I want to check: is there any subtle difference between these versions? And is there any compelling logic to favour one over the others?

Comment: Hi , this table summarize the details https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes

Answer (score 5):

The [K8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes) is detailed but **not very opinionated** regarding this point. Also, it is essential to understand the behavior of the underlying Container Runtime, e.g. [Docker](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#notes), first.

As a good practices, I would recommend the following rules:

- If possible, **work with image defaults**. If your Docker image is preconfigured with a sensible `ENTRYPOINT`, there is no need to define a `command` in K8s configuration. Defining `/bin/sh` in your K8s configuration should almost always be **unnecessary, if your image is preconfigured properly**.

Nevertheless, if you have to overwrite image defaults, I would consider only **two general patterns**:

- **Shell pattern**, where your `command` just provides a shell and your `args` the actual executable plus its arguments. This makes your configuration easy to read and lends itself to complicated `args` that use command chaining.

  ```
  command: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
  args: [ 'python manage.py makemigrations' ]
  ```
- **Exec pattern**, where your `command` provides the executable and the `args` the arguments for that executable. This follows the architectural idea behind splitting the configuration in two parts, where users of images typically only have to modify the `args`.

  ```
  command: [ 'python' ]
  args: [ 'manage.py', 'makemigrations']
  ```

Please note that K8s does **not** permit shell like pattern for the `command`, e.g. the following is not valid configuration:

```
  command: [ '/bin/sh -c' ] << NOT VALID
  args: [ 'python', 'manage.py',  'makemigrations' ]
```

Comment: Specifically, `command: [ '/bin/sh -c' ]` will try to execute the file `sh -c` in the `/bin` directory which, while a syntactically valid filename, is quite unlikely to exist.

Comment: Thanks! So `command: [ 'python', 'manage.py' ]` makes sense architecturally then. As that constitutes the command.